# TypeScript Import Path Alias

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I am currently working on a TypeScript application which is comprised of multiple Node modules written in TypeScript, that are installed into the `node_modules` directory.

Before continuing, I would like to note that I am using TypeScript 2.0, I am not adverse to using the 2.1 dev release if need be as well. I just want to get this working.

The structure of each Node module is something along the lines of:

```
dist/
    es2015/
        index.js
        utils/
            Calculator.js
            Calculator.d.ts
            Date.js
            Date.d.ts
            Flatpack.js
            Flatpack.d.ts
src/
    index.ts
    utils/
        Calculator.ts
        Date.ts
        Flatpack.ts
```

The dist folder is the generated source, with this path being configured using `outDir` inside of my `tsconfig.json` file. I have also configured the `main` property in my `package.json` to be `dist/es2015/index.js`.

**Important things to note:**

- In my project I am using `moduleResolution` type of `node`
- I am using TypeScript 2.0
- I am not asking how to import a file from within the package. I am installing the package via Npm and then importing it via `packagename/` from within an application that is using this module.

Now comes my question/issue. Whilst importing files from this module, I would like to be able to do this:

```
import {Sin, Cos, Tan} from "common-utils/utils/Calculator";
```

However, the file cannot resolve to the `dist/es2015/utils` directory. Ideally I would like my imports to resolve from this specific `dist` folder and not from the root, which is what appears to be happening.

The above import needs to be written as the following to get it to work:

```
import {Sin, Cos, Tan} from "common-utils/dist/es2015/utils/Calculator";
```

However, writing `dist/es2015` each time is not ideal and it just makes some of the imports look really long. Is there a way I can configure my module to resolve to the `dist/es2015` directory? I don't want to have to put in overrides inside of my project, ideally each module would specify where files are resolved from.

If you are still unsure what I am asking (and I apologise if this is confusing) in Jspm when you create a plugin/module to be used with Jspm, you can specify inside of the `package.json` for the module something like the following:

```
  "jspm": {
    "registry": "npm",
    "jspmPackage": true,
    "main": "my-module",
    "format": "amd",
    "directories": {
      "dist": "dist/amd"
    },
```

I am looking for the equivalent of the above in TypeScript (if it exists). A mapping directive, so when the end user runs `npm install my-cool-package` and then in their app tries to import something, all imports by default resolve to the `commonjs` directory (the above example for Jspm uses amd, but same premise).

Is this possible or am I misunderstanding something here? I know some new path mapping features were added into the latest release, but documentation on using them is almost nonexistent.

Comment: if you are importing `Calculator.ts` in `index.ts` you can try `import {Sin,Cos,Tan} from "./utils/Calculator"`

Comment: This would definitely work if importing from within the package itself. However, my issue is that this is a module I install into `node_modules` and then import using `from "packagename/" - the issue is that adding in the direct path to the dist folder feels messy, I would like to alias it to make this the default import location, but do it from within the module, not something I have to configure in the project consuming the module.

Comment: What if you add config object where you can add package name or file name and 'build' your path, also look at system.js or webpack for this tasks

Comment: I was hoping to avoid build tasks for making the path logic work. Having said that, this seems to be the norm for how most CommonJS modules are built.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

So after reading your comment, I realized I misunderstood your question! If you want to control the paths from an imported package's perspective, just use set the `main` property of your `package.json` to a file that properly represents the object graph of your module.

```
{
  "main": "common-utils/dist/es2015/index.js"
}
```

If you're attempting to control the import paths from a project's perspective, what you're looking for is TypeScript 2's new path mapping feature for module resolution. You can enable path mapping by configuring your `tsconfig.json` as follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "angular2/*": ["../path/to/angular2/*"],
      "local/*": ["../path/to/local/modules/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in your TypeScript files, you can import the modules like this:

```
import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/bootstrap';
import { module } from 'local/module';
```

For more details about the Path Mapping feature in TypeScript 2 see [this Github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039).

In your case, I think the following configuration should work:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "common-utils/utils/*": ["./node_modules/common-utils/dist/es2015/utils/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @faraz. I will give this a try sometime this morning. The path configuration goes into my module though, not the project, right? And then the TypeScript compiler when I pull in my module should pick up the paths defined within this file, correct?

Comment: No, the path configuration goes in your TypeScript project, and it should point to the module you want to reference from your project.

Comment: I thought as much as I did get it working similarly within the project. Does this mean what I am asking to do is not currently possible in TypeScript itself from a module perspective? I would love to do the above, but define it in the package itself so when imported, the path aliases are picked up. Jspm allows packages to configure aliases for paths, I was hoping TypeScript offered the same as telling the user to add these path aliases in is a little bit painful. Are multiple wildcards supported within the one pathing glob string?

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your question! I didn't realize you we're trying to direct configuration from packages. Why not just set the `main` property in your `package.json` to an appropriate index file?

Comment: Thanks Faraz. I have accepted your answer. I was hoping to avoid the `index.js` file which exposes my imports. I think I will go the project configuration route, these aren't public modules anyway and they're all living under a scope, so I know the scope is always the same. For public modules, a commonjs based `index.js` file exporting all public facing imports is definitely the way to go. The Aurelia Javascript framework takes this approach as do many other CommonJS modules. Thanks again, well deserved bounty.

Comment: Will this approach let me use `import {Date} from 'common-utils/src/utils/Date'` from a Typescript app and have tsc rewrite it as `dist/....`?

Answer (score 12):

If you are using paths, you will need to change back absolute paths to relative paths for it to work after compiling typescript into plain javascript using `tsc`.

Most popular solution for this has been [tsconfig-paths](https://github.com/dividab/tsconfig-paths) so far.

I've tried it, but it did not work for me for my complicated setup.
Also, it resolves paths in run-time, meaning overhead in terms of your package size and resolve performance.

So, I wrote a solution myself, [tscpaths](https://github.com/joonhocho/tscpaths).

I'd say it's better overall because it replaces paths at compile-time. It means there is no runtime dependency or any performance overhead. It's pretty simple to use. You just need to add a line to your build scripts in `package.json`.

The project is pretty young, so there could be some issues if your setup is very complicated.
It works flawlessly for my setup, though my setup is fairly complex.