# Declaring shared module angular4 with angular like path

Tags: angular, typescript, import, webpack, systemjs

I develop Angular 2 app using SystemJs, Typescript, WebPack. Used https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter as a seed of my project.

I have a SharedModule. It contains some shared models (like Phone.model.ts, User.model.ts) directives, guards and some other minor stuff. 
During the development I was using relative paths to import them like ../../../../shared/models/user.model.ts.
Is there a way to declare a shared module in an Angular-like way (using @ prefix for example) so I could use imports using @shared/models/user.model.ts path ?

Or is there any better solutions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript Import Path Alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601592/typescript-import-path-alias)