# Avoid referencing a npm package scope in TypeScript source

Tags: typescript, npm, scope, private

I have a number of scoped packages in my private npm repo (starting with `@username`; scopes probably more known from angular: `@angular/core`, `@angular/forms` etc).

Now, I am looking for a way to reference the package still the same way without the `@username` prefixed in my `import` statements in TypeScript.

What I have to do now in *every* typescript source file referencing the package:

```
import MyPackage from "@username/mypackage"
```

What I want to be able to do:

```
import MyPackage from "mypackage"
```

(and configure how the @username is resolved somewhere else, i.e. tsconfig.json). Any ideas how to do this?

P.S: I am specifically asking for the TypeScript compiler, not any webpack based solutions (we do not use webpack as its a node project).

(Motivation: In a team, users might replace dependencies with their own implementations from their own branches and repos during development, i.e. we must quickly be able to switch to `@username2/mypackage` but without modifying all our TS sourcecode, let alone commiting this to the sourcecode).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeScript Import Path Alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601592/typescript-import-path-alias) (not quite the same question, but the same answer, I think)

Comment: No, unfortunately that doesn't work; seems to be related to the '@' character (I tested at least on macOS)

Comment: Ah, that sucks. Will retract my close vote, then.