# Browser and nodejs platform abstraction in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm writing a library that might contain different implementations for browser and node.

This is how my directory structure looks like

```
root
├── myclass
│   ├── myclass.d.ts
│   │
│   ├── browser
│   │   └── myclass.ts
│   │
│   └── node
│       └── myclass.ts
│
├── index.ts (references myclass.d.ts)
│
├── tsconfig.browser.json
└── tsconfig.node.json
```

**index.ts**

```
import myclass from "./myclass/myclass"
myclass.print();
```

**myclass\myclass.d.ts**

```
declare class myclass {
    public static print();
}

export default myclass;
```

**myclass\node\myclass.ts**

```
import myclass from "../myclass";

export default class myclass_browser implements myclass {
    public static print() {
        console.log("node");
    }
}
```

I want to have two separate tsconfigs (tsconfig.browser.json and tsconfig.node.json) such that each config will make the compiler output js files containing platform specific implementation.

How do I make typescript compiler pickup the correct implementation based on the config file, and do it such that this is applicable for all classes with such format in the project.

**Update:** Okay so I tried using `paths` in my tsconfig and this is how my `tsconfig.node.json` looks like

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "rootDir": "./",
        "outDir": "../out/node",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "myclass/*": ["./myclass/node/*"]
        }
    }
}
```

However module resolution doesn't work because the compiler stops at `myclass.d.ts`

This is what the resolution trace looks like

```
======== Resolving module './myclass/myclass' from 'D:/tsabs/root/index.ts'. ========
Module resolution kind is not specified, using 'NodeJs'.
Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location 'D:/tsabs/root/myclass/myclass', target file type 'TypeScript'.
File 'D:/tsabs/root/myclass/myclass.ts' does not exist.
File 'D:/tsabs/root/myclass/myclass.tsx' does not exist.
File 'D:/tsabs/root/myclass/myclass.d.ts' exist - use it as a name resolution result.
======== Module name './myclass/myclass' was successfully resolved to 'D:/tsabs/root/myclass/myclass.d.ts'. ========
======== Resolving module '../myclass' from 'D:/tsabs/root/myclass/browser/myclass.ts'. ========
Module resolution kind is not specified, using 'NodeJs'.
Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location 'D:/tsabs/root/myclass/myclass', target file type 'TypeScript'.
File 'D:/tsabs/root/myclass/myclass.ts' does not exist.
File 'D:/tsabs/root/myclass/myclass.tsx' does not exist.
File 'D:/tsabs/root/myclass/myclass.d.ts' exist - use it as a name resolution result.
======== Module name '../myclass' was successfully resolved to 'D:/tsabs/root/myclass/myclass.d.ts'. ========
======== Resolving module '../myclass' from 'D:/tsabs/root/myclass/node/myclass.ts'. ========
Module resolution kind is not specified, using 'NodeJs'.
Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location 'D:/tsabs/root/myclass/myclass', target file type 'TypeScript'.
File 'D:/tsabs/root/myclass/myclass.ts' does not exist.
File 'D:/tsabs/root/myclass/myclass.tsx' does not exist.
File 'D:/tsabs/root/myclass/myclass.d.ts' exist - use it as a name resolution result.
======== Module name '../myclass' was successfully resolved to 'D:/tsabs/root/myclass/myclass.d.ts'. ========
```

Comment: you can use DI/IoC container to register and resolve differently in different entry points. So you will have at least two entry points: browser and node

Comment: any way i can do that without bloating my project with extra typescript libraries?

Comment: Yes, you can. Learn about DI/IoC pattern and come up with implementation. You can reinvent the wheel or use existing solution like https://github.com/mgechev/injection-js  which is TS-friendly, cross-platform DI.

Comment: Is there any way to do it at compile time? Basically make typescript pickup the right file based on config json? Or some custom module resolution?

Comment: OP is right that this should be done in compile time. DI/IoC is pattern for runtime substitution. Nevertheless, i don't know yet how to implement it using `tsconfig.json` only. It can be done using `webpack`'s `resolve` feature.

Comment: Looks like `compilerOptions.paths` property of `tsconfig.json` can solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601592/typescript-import-path-alias

Comment: @ZbigniewZagórski, sorry i got overexcited last time and commented that it worked (when i didn't exactly try it out properly).

Comment: Well, how do you start your app ? `ts-node` or `tsc & node` ?
If `ts-node` - you may try this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/tsconfig-paths as `ts-node` by default ignores some parts of `tsconfig.json` ...