# typescript - importing custom class using "@" sign

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, path

I've seen occurrences when we import a package in the following way

```
import { SharedModule } from '@shared/shared.module';
```

*@shared* in this case refers to the folder located in our project

```
/src/shared
```

I am looking to avoid importing my class in a classic way using dots and slashes at the beginning (relative path approach), e.g.

```
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: What you want is probably typescript path aliases, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38677886/9907293).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Basically you are looking for something called `alias`.

To be able to use aliases we have to add baseUrl and paths properties to our tsconfig.json file like this -

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "...": "reduced for brevity",

    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@env/*": ["environments/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

So now you are able to import your files with `@app` or `@env`.

For more in detail you can refer to this awesome article.

- https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/6-best-practices-pro-tips-for-angular-cli-better-developer-experience-7b328bc9db81#3144

Answer (score 4):

`alias` will help here. For adding it, modify `tsconfig.json` by adding it in paths as:

```
{
  ...
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@app/*": ["app/*"],
      "@env/*": ["environments/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["app/shared/*"]
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

You will be able to import `shared` module as:

```
import { SharedModule } from '@shared/shared.module';
```