# can't use local npm package with typescript

Tags: typescript, npm

I created a local npm package called "common" consisting of minimal package.json and a file foo.ts

I have it referenced the package.json of my project like follows :

```
"dependencies": {
   "common": "file:common",
}
```

When I reference my common module in my code it won't compile.

this code :

```
import 'common/models/foo'
```

crashes :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'common/foo'
```

What am I missing out on ?

Comment: TypeScript compiler does not recognize "dependencies" property in `package.json`, you have to configure path mapping also in `tsconfig.json` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38677886/43848)

Comment: tried path mapping and it doesn't work either