# Declare a universally importable module in TypeScript by an alias

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

All,

I have a file

```
// ./theme/theme.ts
export const theme = {}
```

All React components must now refer to resolve this module by relative path

```
import {theme} from '../theme/theme'
// or
import {theme} from '../../theme/theme'
```

Is there away to avoid this and simply:

```
declare module theme {
  export const theme = myTheme
}
```

I tried modifying `tsconfig.json`'s baseUrl and path properties to no avail

Answer (score 0):

If your question is same as I understand, please refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38677886/2514158)

Whilst, using the alias will still follow the path declaration syntax i.e.

```
import {...} from 'aliasSample/moduleSample'
```

If I haven't fit the question content, try to write an explanative comment, hence I can edit my answer