# Node module: auto generate entry point from all project exports

Tags: npm, nodes, node-modules

I have a package with the following structure:

```
components/
  Button/
    Button.tsx
    index.tsx
  Icon/
    Icon.tsx
    index.tsx
```

I am exporting this as an npm package, to be consumed by another repo.
In the importing repo, I am currently importing like so:

```
import Button from "my-package/components/Button"
import Icon from "my-package/components/Icon"
```

What I would like to do is import them like so:

```
import { Button, Icon } from "my-package"
```

I am aware that to do so, I need to define an [entry point](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/esm.html#esm_package_entry_points). However it seems like I will need to manually import/export all the components to and from the entry point file.

Is there a way to automatically generate such an entry point file, without all the required manual effort?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript Import Path Alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601592/typescript-import-path-alias)

Comment: @mamichels I don't believe it does. Because (as far as I can tell) that's aliasing the destination in the target repo to reflect the structure of the module.

What I am looking to do is automatically update the structure of the exported module such that everything can be imported from the root, much like one can do `import { useState} from 'React'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722270/is-it-possible-to-import-modules-from-all-files-in-a-directory-using-a-wildcard

Comment: If you ever find an answer to your question, please share it. Manually managing an index is a PITA. I have scripts to do it for me (scan the src folder for all files and add entry in a index.ts but it ain't pretty...)