# Can I use tsconfig's path aliases for an imported NPM package?

Tags: javascript, npm, tsconfig

I develop a js package that I intend to publish in NPM.
It has several parts, and I'm using tsconfig's `paths` property to reference them in import.

So, lets say my package is called `@myApp/infra`, I registered these paths: `@myApp/infra/comm` and `myApp/infra/i18n`.

But - when I install this npm package and import the code - I can't use these paths.
Is there a way to publish the package with that import structure?

Comment: I think it's what you're looking for.[TypeScript Import Path Alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38601592/typescript-import-path-alias)

Comment: This handles case of one alias. But I have several aliases in the package.