# Path Aliases and Index Files

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm using Next.js with TypeScript and I'm configuring path aliases in my project and goes just fine. But I have a little trouble with `index.ts` files inside folders, I want to do something like this:

```js
// interfaces/index.ts
export type { IProfile }

// page/index.tsx
import { IProfile } from '@/interfaces';
```

This code throws me the following error:

> Cannot find module '@interfaces;' or its corresponding type declarations.

Obviously, the solution is to import using `@/interfaces/index` but I want to avoid that. There is any solution for this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38677886/15304814

Comment: What does your `tsconfig.json` file look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question but here's an answer for you.

If you're using index files to export your functions and you don't want to type `@/interfaces/index` everytime you want to import something from your `interfaces` directory, you'd rather simply type `@/interfaces`.

In your tsconfig file, try something like this:

```
"paths": {
  "@/interfaces": ["src/interfaces/index"], // or wherever your folder lives
}
```

And then you can simply import the desired function like so:

```
import { IProfile } from '@/interfaces';
```

This works because your path alias is looking directly at your index file in the interfaces folder.

Hope this helps :)

Cheers, and happy coding!