# NgModule decorator in service class

Tags: angular

Both services of the following code snippet depending on different modules, can I just add a `@NgModule({ imports: [... ]})` decorator to each service class to manage the dependencies?

I don't want to add the modules in app.module.ts, because each service depends on different modules and I want less effort to exchange both services, I only want to modify (1) and (2):

app.modules.ts

```
import { Connector } from './class/connector';
import { SqlConnectorService } from './class/sql-connector.service';//(1)

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: Connector, useClass: SqlConnectorService }],//(2)
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

connector.ts

```
export abstract class Connector {
    abstract connect(): void;
}
```

sql-connector.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class SqlConnectorService extends Connector {

  constructor() { super(); }
  connect() { }
}
```

nosql-connector.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class NosqlConnectorService extends Connector {

  constructor() { super(); }
  connect() { }
  
}
```

Comment: what exactly should be in those different modules? some other services? or components/directives as well?

Comment: also what angular version are you using? there is probably a more elegant solution with one of the newer versions

Comment: @Andrei `Angular CLI: 16.0.1, Node: 18.16.0, Package Manager: npm 9.5.1`. I mean when work with NosqlConnectorService, then I want to load `AngularFireModule` as well. And if I change to SqlConnectorService, then I don't need to import `AngularFireModule`.

Comment: there is an Alexander's answer where 2 modules, instead of just services could do the thing for you and I think that is the best solution here. Just take into consideration that all eagerly imported modules are providing all of their providers into a single injector instance. i.e. if you import both of the modules, you will most likely receive issues with collisions = services overwrites by something from another module

Comment: @Andrei, I have already discussed this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76565012/make-angular-modules-easily-exchangeable) before I came up with this questions and mentioned the difficulties I see in it. I was advised differently there, which brings me to this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think what you've proposed is possible. I suggest creating a `SqlConnectorModule` and a `NoSqlConnectorModule` which import the necessary other modules and provide the `Connector` service. That way, your client app just needs to import the appropriate module and it will have access to the appropriate `Connector`.

Comment: I also thought about this before and tried to discus it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76565012/make-angular-modules-easily-exchangeable).

Comment: You don't have to import the service from the modules where you use it: you simply import the `Connector` interface and Angular will inject the concrete class you provide in whichever module you import.